# How do I Embed file in excel, use it and then embed new version again into excel workbook I'm creating a new Userform control for excel?

Tags: vba, excel, user-controls, userform

I'm creating a custom Usercontrol (Userform) for excel, the name is Virtual forms.
The control is storing data in external file that is created in the same folder where the workbook is (example: VFFile.vf).
How to embed this file into excel (maybe OLEObject? or is there some other solution?)

More info:
I created a Usercotrol (ActiveX control) for excel, which uses an external file with definitions (VFFile.vf). And now to avoid that the developer always has to define the filename where this file on his computer is, I would like to somehow incorporate the file into Excel (when he drops this control onto excel worksheet the control will also put this file into excel workbook). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit what you mean? There are many possible ways to access non-Excel files in the same directory. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I have edited the question. Is now at least a little more clearly what I want to ask?

Comment: Can you store the data on a worksheet in the same workbook? You could optionally hide the worksheet so your user wouldn't be able to view it.

Comment: PeterT thank you for your suggestion. Yes, this is one way (even if it is a dozen tables with data). But I would also  like to, over time, expand the control to Word and Powerpoint.

Comment: There are many code examples for storing data using VBA in different file formats. Search for "VBA to store data in INI files" or "VBA to store data in XML files" to research whatever is best for you.

Comment: Hello PeterT and Thank You for your answer. But I would like to "hide" this file into the workbook so that the user or the developer (because I'm building an ActiveX control for developers) don't need to take care of it. If he/she distribute this workbook, he doesn't need to bother with this file because it is integrated into Workbook. I'm sure that there is a way, because how do other developers build their controls or Addins for VBA and only the control is ever visible to the user, but how they deal with properties and other definitions that their controls use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continue to use an external file because it gives me the possibilities to use this control in other environments, not only VBA with Excel.

For example, I can use it also in Python, or C# or VB.net.

Thank you guys for your tips and directions.

Davor